# The pattern of named function expression inside function

Tags: javascript, function, jestjs

The following code is taken from the Jest source code:

```
function _path() {
  const data = _interopRequireDefault(require('path'));

  _path = function _path() {
    return data;
  };

  return data;
}
```

Why do we have the named function expression in the middle? How and when could that pattern be used?

Comment: This makes `const data = _interopRequireDefault(require('path'));` only being executed the first time the function is called. However, note that this looks like transpiled code, so this may be something that Babel does. I'd check the original source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer function is called `_path`. Then inside it the line `_path = function _path()` overwrites the `_path` variable (currently assigned to the `_path` function) with another function called `_path`.

So, when executed the function *overwrites* itself with a new function that will do a different thing. Here is a simple illustration of this principle:

```js
function f() {
  console.log("outer");
  f = function f() {
    console.log("inner");
  }
}

f(); //outer
f(); //inner
f(); //inner
```

So, this is *what* it's doing. As for *why* it's doing it - caching. It only needs to look up/calculate a value once and then every other execution will be cached.  So, here is an example where `lookup` is a mock stand-in for a network operation.

```js
function lookup() {
  console.log("making a network call");
  return 4;
}

function f() {
  var output = lookup();

  f = function f() {
    return output;
  }
  
  return output;
}

console.log(f()); //network call -> 4
console.log(f()); //4
console.log(f()); //4
```

The same can be done with a heavy calculation that doesn't require a network call - instead of repeating the calculation and using up the CPU cycles every time, the result can only be calculated once.

Finally, why the inner function is called `_path` - there is no strict reason to call it that. The code would work the same even if it didn't have a name. However, it *does* replace the outer function, so preserving the name is a good idea. It can also aid in debugging, when you see the stack trace.

In general, this technique is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Side-note: that's the correct spelling, no **r**. Although I doubt anybody would be confused if you put it in.

At any rate,  memoization involves calculating a function once and only returning the result every other time. A generic approach is to have a `memoize` function that you can decorate other functions with. Here is a sample implementation:

```js
function memoize(func) {
  //keep a cache for all results
  const cache = {};
  
  //make a new function
  const memo = function() {
    //get the arguments from the input
    var key = JSON.stringify(...arguments);

    let result;
    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //get result from cache
      result = cache[key];
    } else {
      //calculate the result and put it in the cache
      result = func(...arguments);
      cache[key] = result;
    }

    return result;
  }
  
  return memo;
}

function lookup(data) {
  console.log("network call");
  return data + 4;
}

function calculate(data) {
  console.log("heavy operation");
  return data + 2;
}

let memLookup = memoize(lookup);
console.log(memLookup(4)); //network call -> 8
console.log(memLookup(4)); //8
console.log(memLookup(6)); //network call -> 10
console.log(memLookup(6)); //10

let memCalculate = memoize(calculate);
console.log(memCalculate(4)); //heavy operation -> 6
console.log(memCalculate(4)); //6
console.log(memCalculate(6)); //heavy operation -> 8
console.log(memCalculate(6)); //8
```